# Moving from VB5 to VB.NET and having problems with USB .dll calls

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to communicate with a usb device that uses the FDTI 232RL.  I've installed the drivers and integrated the .dll calls into my VB5 code and it works well.  I want to get this to work on VB.net but I get the PInvokeStackImballance error message.  In VB5 I have the following code sequence:

```
Private Declare Function FT_ListDevices Lib "FTD2XX.DLL" (ByVal arg1 As Long, ByVal arg2 As String, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
...
Dim strSerialNumber As String * 256
...
LoggerList.AddItem ("ListDevices by S/N")
If FT_ListDevices(0, strSerialNumber, FT_LIST_BY_INDEX Or FT_OPEN_BY_SERIAL_NUMBER) <> FT_OK Then
...
```

In VB.NET:

```
Private Declare Function FT_ListDevices Lib "FTD2XX.DLL" (ByVal arg1 As Long, ByVal arg2 As String, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
...
Dim strSerialNumber As Stringbuilder new = stringbuilder (" ",256)
...
LoggerList.AddItem ("ListDevices by S/N")
If FT_ListDevices(0, strSerialNumber, FT_LIST_BY_INDEX Or FT_OPEN_BY_SERIAL_NUMBER) <> FT_OK Then
...
```

The error occurs at the if statement.  Do I need to import the Dll with import("FTD2XX.dll")?  I've also tried `Dim strSerialNumber(256) as char` and that doesn't work either.  Am I working the wrong problem?

Answer (score 2):

In VB5 a `long` is 32 bits while it is 64 its in VB.Net.  Change the parameters in your function from `long` to `int` which is 32 bits on VB.Net.

```
Private Declare Function FT_ListDevices Lib "FTD2XX.DLL" (ByVal arg1 As Integer, _
        ByVal arg2 As String, ByVal dwFlags As Integer) As Integer
```

Comment: Thanks.  It no longer "crashes" but the call doesn't work yet.  I'll keep working on that but your comment was very helpful